# Multiple filter options in view. Setting them filters correctly. Setting only one 'disables' the filter

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have two forms.

The first submits to the database. Works perfectly. 
The second retrieves the database information, also works fine.

However, I have filters within the form that are not working perfectly.

I have several filters.

- Location
- Type
- Date Range

If all filters are set, they work.

If only one is set, they do not work. I can't figure out why this is happening.

forms.py (Filter Form):

```
class OvertimeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Location.objects.all(),
        empty_label="All Locations",
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    overtime_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=overtimeTypes.objects.all(),
        empty_label='All Types', 
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    dateStart = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))

    dateEnd = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Overtime
        fields = ['location']
        fields = ['overtime_type']
        field = ['dateStart']
        field = ['dateEnd']
```

views.py (Filter Form):

```
def Overtime_Results(request):
    userGroup = request.user.groups.get(name__in=['Comp1' ,'Comp2' , 'Comp3' , 'Comp4'])
    overtime_data = Overtime.objects.filter(client__name=userGroup)
    location = None
    overtime_type = None
    dateStart = date.today()
    dateEnd = date.today()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OvertimeForm(data=request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        location = form.data['location']
        dateStart = form.data['dateStart']
        dateEnd = form.data['dateEnd']
        overtime_type = form.data['overtime_type']

        #This is where I think the problem is, something here isn't correct.
        overtime_data = Overtime.objects.filter(location=location, overtime_type=overtime_type, overtimeDateStart__range=(dateStart, dateEnd), client__name=userGroup) 

        return response
else:
    form = OvertimeForm()

template_name = "overtime/Overtime_Results.html"
context = {
    'form': form,
    'location': location,
    'overtime_type': overtime_type,  
    'overtime_data': overtime_data,
}

return render(request, template_name, context)
```

In the html file:

```
    <div class="col-md-3">{{ form.location }} 
      {{ form.dateStart }} <p>To</p>
      {{ form.dateEnd }}
      {{ form.overtime_type }}
    </div>
```

This is how the form looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5YY9.jpg

Comment: 1) ModelForms exist to help you build forms from models. Why do you use a `ModelForm` if you are redefining so many fields? Are those fields in the `Overtime` model already?  2) make the `fields` attribute a list (or a tuple) of the model attributes you want in the form, e.g. `fields = ['location', 'overtime_type', 'dateStart', 'dateEnd']`. Please read the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) carefully

Comment: What does "they do not work" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: @Pynchia Mainly because I'm still developing my knowledge and I wasn't sure a tuple would be better in this case. Can you clarify WHY a tuple would actually change the results of this? All the original fields are present in the Overtime model. I assumed a second form referencing these fields was the best approach to creating filters in a form.

Comment: @Sayse No errors. The filter just doesn't work and displays everything as if no filters had been set.

Comment: I said a list OR a tuple. No difference functionally. Your code is wrongly assigning values to `fields` (and `field` maybe a typo) several times, overriding each previous assignment. Use a `Form` in case you want to completely redefine the fields in it. Otherwise, if you want to avoid writing code twice, use a `modelForm` and simply specify which fields in the model should be used to build the form. Read the docs

Comment: @Pynchia YOu're completely right, I was simply just overwriting existing fields. Granted, this made no difference in the grander scheme. Really stupid on my part, but definitely not the reason for the filter not working appropriately.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but you should use a GET request here.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Ignore that, I forgot to change that back. It is GET!

Answer (score 0):

You should build up your query with those filters that you actually care about, split up the creation of the queryset, this will still only result in one call to the db, its just much cleaner.

```
overtime_data = Overtime.objects.all()
location = form.cleaned_data.get('location')
if location:
    overtime_data = overtime_data.filter(location=location)
# continue for other params.
```

You were also using `form.data` instead of `cleaned_data` which means you weren't using the validated data.

Comment: Will review and get back to you! Thank you.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the delay, I was out of town for a couple days and I've just got into trying this solution. I'm actually a little confused on where I should be place my view, I assume the queryset is in the `if form_is_valid()` right? I'm trying the method you've recommended, but I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: @AaronLayfield - Yeah it essentially replaces where your existing `overtime_data` was... that wouldn't solve the issue though, its more that you needed to use `cleaned_data` instead of `data` I believe

Comment: Yeah, I tried using the cleaned data and that didn't solve it, the update / method you've recommended doesn't change the outcome either, though I can definitely see the logic behind this. Seems no matter what I change, because the field is set to 'None' it'll return everything. I need some way of saying `if None then change value to return all`